# How to grep folder that contains UTF-16 or UTF-32 encoded files?

Tags: linux, encoding, grep, utf-16, utf-32

There exist three identical `txt`-files in one folder and each file has only one word inside: "hello". First file is encoded in `UTF-8`, second one in `UTF-16` and the last in `UTF-32` (all files created on linux). But using grep

```
grep -i "hello" *.txt
```

returns only one result, it's the `UTF-8`-file. Grep does not find the other two files.

How can I grep a folder that partially contains `UTF-16` or `UTF-32` encoded files?

Comment: What kind of text are you greping? Just ASCII text in UTF-16 or more complex (and generalized solution)?

Comment: As described, just simple text. Textfile contains just one single word: "hello", pls. see above.

Comment: grep -ai 'h.e.l.l.o' [UTF16] and with 3 dots [UTF32]. This works without requirement to know the endianess or parting BOM. (better to use `\0` (but more complex to include on redex) instead of `.`

Comment: I'm surprised, `grep -ai 'h.e.l.l.o'` finds all UTF-16 files.

Comment: ASCII code `xx` is `xx` in UTF-8, `00 xx` or `xx 00`  (but same form in the same file) on UTF-16 and `00 00 00 xx` or `xx 00 00 00` in UTF-32. This works just for ASCII characters. \0 is usually ignored in shell (it is used on some commands, e.g. `find`, `xargs`)

Answer (score 2):

One way uses `perl` instead of `grep`:

```
$ perl -CO -Mopen="IN,:encoding(UTF-16)" -ne 'print if /hello/i' utf16_file.txt
```

with the obvious change for the UTF-32 files.

This tells `perl` to use UTF-8 for output, that files opened for reading are encoded in UTF-16, and only print the lines that (case-insensitively) match the regular expression inside the `//`'s.

Or use `iconv` to convert the file first:

```
$ iconv -f UTF-16 -t UTF-8 utf16_file.txt | grep -i hello
```

---

If you don't have an easy way to tell from the filename what encoding it is, maybe something like this script that uses `file` to try to guess the encoding and then `iconv` to convert to UTF-8 to feed to GNU grep:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

# This assumes we're running in a UTF-8 locale
to_charset=UTF-8

regexp="$1"
shift 1

for file in "$@"; do
    case "$(file "$file")" in
        *UTF-16*) charset=UTF-16;;
        *UTF-32*) charset=UTF-32;;
        *UTF-8*) charset=UTF-8;;
        *ASCII*) charset=ASCII;;
        *) echo "$file has an unknown encoding." >&2
           charset=ASCII;;
    esac
    #echo "Using $charset for $file"
    iconv -f "$charset" -t "$to_charset" "$file" | \
        grep -i -H --label "$file" "$regexp"
done
```

Usage: `smartgrep hello *.txt`

Answer (score 1):

[ripgrep](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep) is a very good alternative to many grep programs (including GNU grep) which has the advantage to find the requested string/pattern regardless of text encoding (UTF-8, UTF-16, latin-1, GBK, EUC-JP, Shift_JIS and more)

You can use the same way as grep

```
$ rg -i pattern *.txt
```

This chart compares the different *greplike* tools:
https://beyondgrep.com/feature-comparison/